# Velocity #foreach not working for dynamic value(range)

Tags: java, spring, foreach, velocity

I'm trying to implement     #foreach   of velocity, after much of debugging I found that if I implement the #foreach for static values it executes fine but when the #foreach range is decided by a dynamic variable (whose value is received from servlet) the #foreach fails, below is the snippet from my html file (.vm) :

Below case runs fine:

```
#set($start = 1)  
#set($end   = 5)     
#set($range = [$start..$end])

#foreach ($number in $range)
   $number ,                 ##display on html page
#end
```

Output:

```
 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ,
```

But below case fails: ($count is a property defined in controller servlet)

```
#set($start = 1)
#set($end   = $count)
#set($range = [$start..$end])

#foreach ($number in $range)
  $number ,                  ##display on html page
#end
```

Output is blank.

To verify if $count holds the value I displayed $count and $end, they both display correct values. When I tried displaying $range it was displayed as it is -> "$range" as if its a string on html page and not a velocity variable! I'm stuck, kindly help me to figure out what is going wrong. Thanks in advance!

I am using netbeans and using velocity with spring mvc, I have included all the required jar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `VelocityTools`, the proper references are $request and $response

The methods name is `getAttribute`

```
$request.getAttribute('count')
```

or just

```
$request.count
```